# History API. Переход по ссылкам

Tags: javascript, jquery, html5-history-api, history-api

С главной страницы сайта перехожу на страницу с категориями, где товар прогружается ajax-ом. Также на странице есть пагинация. При переходе между страницами в пагинации, формирую запрос ajax и вызываю функцию history.pushState(), где передаю текущий урл страницы:

```
function loadProducts() {
       //Загрузка товаров
        history.pushState(null, null, url);
    }

 $(window).bind("popstate",function(event){
        currentPage();//Парсим текущий url для получения страницы
        loadProducts();
    });
```

Не получается перейти на главную. Как это сделать? Почему можно перейти только на одну страницу назад?

Comment: Ничего не понятно. Где не получается? О какой одной странице назад речь? Что такое currentPage? Зачем loadProducts вызывается при событии popstate?

Comment: товары загружаются не все на страницу каталога, поэтому я использую пагинацию. Так как если нажать кнопку назад в браузере, то мы вернемся на предыдущую страницу в пагинации и необходимо опять загрузить товары.

Answer (score 0):

history.pushState(), по сути ничгего сама не делае, а играет с кэшом. По сути вы можете использовать barba js или pjax, но это так себе варианты, сейчас используют реактивные фремворки vue js или react . Но там проблемы с индексированием. В вашем случае необходим подгрузить данные, а потом к ним обращаться

Comment: barbara.js => barba.js

Comment: спвсибо просто не пользуюсь в памяти заело barbara.js